# Connecting from Work to home-

Tags: remote-access

Any thoughts on how I can connect to my Ubuntu PC at home from work given they don't allow outbound VPN connections from the office?
For my XP machine, I use logmein.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's actually lots of ways around this by using ssh inside the company to setup an outbound tunnel ahead of time over an existing "safe" port. Though that doesn't change the fact that you're probably circumventing their security policy and it's only a matter of time before you're found out and disciplinary actions are taken. I don't wish to document the details of accomplishing this, this is a social problem, contact your IS dept and work something out before you start breaking the rules at your workplace.

Comment: yeah- i don't want to go this route!  I was given a hard time just for asking network support why I can't VPN to my home PC!

Comment: Well, they're responsible for the security of the business, if you connect an unauthorized client to network that has free reign to well everything, they won't know to even scan that node to  see  if it's fit for service or properly segment the networks to limit the damage. It's not just viruses you need to worry about, think disgruntled spouse/friend who pops on to your home computer, that's now always connected to the company lan. VPN done right means they can shutdown that LAN and leave everyone else up, when you go around them, they have to shutdown everyone. Good luck with your new job!

Comment: Actually I phrased my initial question wrongly- I meant to say VNC, not VPN.  I can't make outbound VNC connections from work.  I used to be able to do that at my last job...Sorry for getting you worked up!

Answer (score 0):

Use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/linux.aspx)

Install one copy at your office PC and one at your home ubuntu, they provide unique ID for each installation and you can access your office machine from home without any hassle.

This even have the feature of virtual VPN where it will give you a private IP for you machine which you can use to for RDP as well.

Comment: I have actually used TV between Windows machines- it's available on my Liberkey suite.  Never thought it would be available on Ubuntu as well.  I will try it out today itself.  Thanks Vijay